# problem with conversion of output from linq query to list<> in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have a Software titles class which is defined as follows:

```
public class SoftwareTitles
{

string softwareTitle;
string invoiceNumber;

public SoftwareTitles(string softwareTitle, string invoiceNumber)
{
    this.softwareTitle = softwareTitle;
    this.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
}

public string InvoiceNumber
{
    get
    {
        return this.invoiceNumber;
    }
}

public string SoftwareTitle
{
    get
    {
        return this.softwareTitle;
    }
}
```

}

and i'm getting software titles and invoice numbers from my linq query which i want to store in a list using the following code:

```
   List<SoftwareTitles> softwareTitlesList = new List<SoftwareTitles>();
var result = (from CustomersRecord custRecords in custRecordContainer select new { InvoiceNumber = custRecords.InvoiceNumber, SoftwareTitle = custRecords.InvoiceNumber }).ToList();
        softwareTitlesList = result;
```

But it is freaking out giving me this error:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SoftwareTitles>'
```

Can any one help me ?

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: This has nothing to do with the answer, but notice that you are creating your objects using 2 custRecords.InvoiceNumber.  It looks like you intended: {custRecords.SoftwareTitle, custRecords.InvoiceNumber}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are creating an anonymous type:

```
select new { InvoiceNumber = custRecords.InvoiceNumber, SoftwareTitle = custRecords.InvoiceNumber }
```

and you are trying to build a list of SoftwareTitles.  I am not 100% on the syntax, but try using:

```
select new SoftwareTitle( custRecords.SoftwareTitle, custRecords.InvoiceNumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `select` code

```
select new { 
       InvoiceNumber = custRecords.InvoiceNumber, 
       SoftwareTitle = custRecords.InvoiceNumber 
}
```

is returning an **annonymous type**. You can't put your annonymous type into a `List<SoftwareTitles>`.

Two solutions:

1) You can select an annonymous type if you let the compiler determine the type of your list using the `var` keyword

```
var myList = from CustomersRecord custRecords 
              in custRecordContainer 
               select new { 
                   InvoiceNumber = custRecords.InvoiceNumber, 
                   SoftwareTitle = custRecords.InvoiceNumber 
             }).ToList();
```

2) Map to a `SoftwareTitle` object in your `Select`

```
List<SoftwareTitle> myList = from CustomersRecord custRecords 
                              in custRecordContainer 
                               select new SoftwareTitle { 
                                  InvoiceNumber = custRecords.InvoiceNumber, 
                                  SoftwareTitle = custRecords.InvoiceNumber 
                               }).ToList();
```

I would guess you probably want to do it the 2nd way. Using a list of annonymous type is only really useful as an intermediate step in a function, as you generally can't pass it as a function paramater somewhere else.